# Issue with optimizing parameters in basic multi-layer perceptron

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've just recently been getting into Tensorflow but I've been having some trouble expanding from a simple one layer neural network to a multilayer one. I've pasted the code below from my attempt, any help with why it's not working would be greatly appreciated!

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import trange
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

# Import data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("datasets/MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
W0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 500]))
b0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([500]))
y0 = tf.matmul(x, W0) + b0
relu0 = tf.nn.relu(y0)
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([500, 100]))
b1= tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100]))
y1 = tf.matmul(relu0, W1) + b1
relu1 = tf.nn.relu(y1)
W2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100, 10]))
b2= tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))
y2 = tf.matmul(relu1, W2) + b2
y = y2


# Define loss and optimizer
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
cross_entropy =       tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

# Create a Session object, initialize all variables
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
# Train
for _ in trange(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)    
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

# Test trained model
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
print('Test accuracy: {0}'.format(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: 
mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels})))

sess.close()
```

PS: I know that this code can be achieved much more easily by using Keras or even the prebuilt Tensorflow layers, but I am trying to get a more basic understanding on the math behind the library. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 things to take into consideration.

1) `tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784, 500]))` change this with `tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 500]))` As it is better to have random initialization of weights rather than defining them as 0 s from the start. By making it 0 initially (meaning everything gets the same value) model will follow the same gradient path and will be unable to learn. For the start change every `zeros` with `random_normal`. There are better ways to firstly define variables but this will give you a good start

2) your learning rate is too high 
`train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)` change this line to

```
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.005).minimize(cross_entropy)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment! For some reason, even after fixing these lines I am still looking at accuracy rates of around 10%, which is equivalent to guessing on the MNIST dataset. Is there by any chance a more critical issue with my model?

Comment: Did you change all the `tf.zeros` with `tf.random_normal` ? Because with this model I'm getting 88% test accuracy.

Comment: `By making it 0 model is unable to compute gradient` - This is incorrect.

Comment: Technically yes, you are right. I didn't want to go into details, I will edit that line. It would have been more appropriate to say that the model is stuck into some local minima, it behaves like a linear model. Plus all neurons starting with the same value will go the same way when calculating the gradient.